# each.value cannot be used in this context

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, for-loop, foreach, terraform

I am getting the below error

```
Error: each.value cannot be used in this context
    on main.tf line 11, in locals:
       11:     resourcelist = {for r in local.vnetlist : r.region => each.value }
```

A reference to "each.value" has been used in a context in which it unavailable, such as when the configuration no longer contains the value in its "for_each" expression.

Remove this reference to each.value in your configuration to work around
this error.

```
    locals {
        vnetlist = csvdecode(file("./title.csv"))
        vnetnames = ([for vnets in lookup(data.azurerm_resources.spokes, "resources", []) : lookup(vnets, "name")])
        
    
        for_each = toset(vnetnames)
        resourcelist = {for r in local.vnetlist : r.region => each.value }
    }

output "mybranch" {
  value =  local.resourcelist
}
```

Comment: The `for_each` meta-argument is not valid in a `locals` block. You need to remove that and then update your `resourcelist` accordingly. In this specific situation, you are attempting to co-iterate on `vnetlist` and `vnetname`. You probably need to construct a map between the two with a data transformation. We need to see an example snippet of `vnetlist` to assist further.

Comment: vnetlist = csvdecode(file("./final.csv"))

It is csv file which has the following values
Name,size,region
,,bbbb
,,cccc
,,dddd

I need to iterate through the values in the region column and replace it with the list of vnetnames which I get from the data resources block

Answer (score 0):

The each.key and each.value are attributes for for_each meta-argument and not for.

I guess you need something like that :

```
for_each = toset(vnetnames)

resourcelist = { for k, v in local.vnetlist : k => v.region }
```